# Can't prune git remotes

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an issue while trying to prune our git repo. Pruning works for remotes/origin but another developer has put in remotes/[his username]. Can I prune these? Right now I get a authentication error. He doesn't work for us any more and I needs to clean up some of his commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being `git remote rm the-remote-repo-name` Example - `git remote rm jtrepo`

Comment: That's the way to go. You don't have the proper credentials to connect to that remote apparently anyways. So just remove it.

Answer (score -1):

With Atlassian Stash, in order to delete branches that you don't have branch-level permissions for requires you to have Repository Administrator or Project Administrator permissions. BitBucket is a different product with a different feature set; you may want to [start here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Git+branch+management) for information on Git branch management with BitBucket.

If you're trying to delete branches on the BitBucket repository, there are some things to check:

1. Has `Deny non-fast-forwards` or `Deny branch deletions` been set on the BitBucket repository? If so, the repository administrator must temporarily unset one or both of them temporarily to allow branch deletions.
2. Stash supports branch-level permissions, but BitBucket doesn't. You either have write access, or you don't. Are you *sure* you have write access to the remote repository?
3. If the two previous solutions don't set you straight, then you'll need to improve your question with some screenshots of the permissions and actual error messages if you want further help. Good luck!

Comment: it has nothing to do with Atlassian Stash and permisions. It's just an authentication error.

Comment: @GregoryPakosz There are all kinds of authentication errors. Please feel free to add your own answer based on the thorough and detailed error messages the OP included in his question...if you can find them. Good luck!

Comment: HUGS @CodeGnome. Don't cry for those 2 reputation points. Your Atlassian Stash paragraph is all made up and pruning a remote has nothing to do with non fast forward pushes or branch deletion anyways. I agree "clean up some of his commits" in OP's question is confusing. Yet, he just wants to prune the remote John Doe added before getting fired. Despite the lack of details, you can figure out they just unplugged John Doe's machine or revoked his username on the domain, or alike. Hence removing the remote entirely is fine and OP's answered his own question.